# PHP & MySQL: make chemical reaction

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 tables
1- `tbl_reaction` like this:

```
╔════╦═══════════╦════════════╦═════════╗
║ id ║ condition ║ phenomenon ║  infor  ║
╠════╬═══════════╬════════════╬═════════╣
║  1 ║ abcd123   ║ abcd123    ║ abcd123 ║
║  2 ║ wer       ║ wer        ║ wer     ║
╚════╩═══════════╩════════════╩═════════╝
```

2- `tbl_reaction_item` like this:

```
╔══════╦═══════════╦═════════╦═════╗
║ reid ║ substance ║  type   ║ num ║
╠══════╬═══════════╬═════════╬═════╣
║    1 ║ H2        ║ income  ║   2 ║
║    1 ║ O2        ║ income  ║   1 ║
║    1 ║ H2O       ║ outcome ║   2 ║
╚══════╩═══════════╩═════════╩═════╝
```

What is mysql query to display the reaction:

income + income = outcome

**2H2 + O2 => 2H2O**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [ask] and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). And for formatting: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: how to get value from mysql and display the reaction like above

Comment: **Formatting is everything**. Please add description what you need plus what have you tried so far.

Comment: I try to explain it. what is mysql query to display the reaction like this:

(income + income => outcome)
H2 + O2 => H2O

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> what is mysql query to display the reaction like this: (income +
>   income => outcome) H2 + O2 => H2O

```
SELECT CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN type='income' THEN CONCAT(IF(num=1, '', num),substance) END SEPARATOR ' + '), ' => ',
             GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN type='outcome' THEN CONCAT(IF(num=1, '', num),substance) END SEPARATOR ' + '))
             AS reaction
FROM tbl_reaction_item
GROUP BY reid;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7740fb/6/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔══════════════════╗
║     reaction     ║
╠══════════════════╣
║ 2H2 + O2 => 2H2O ║
╚══════════════════╝
```

How it works:

1. Utilize `GROUP_CONCAT` with custom separator `' + '` to build left and right side.
2. Use `CONCAT` to join both sides with `=>`
3. Use conditional aggregation to get income/outcome respectively
4. Remove num `1` using `IF` function (could also use `CASE`)

---

Consider adding position column to get always the same order of concatenated string parts using [`GROUP_CONCAT(... ORDER BY pos)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
╔══════╦═══════════╦═════════╦═════╦══════╗
║ reid ║ substance ║  type   ║ num ║ pos  ║
╠══════╬═══════════╬═════════╬═════╬══════╣
║    1 ║ H2        ║ income  ║   2 ║   1  ║     -- hydrogen always first
║    1 ║ O2        ║ income  ║   1 ║   2  ║     -- second oxygen
║    1 ║ H2O       ║ outcome ║   2 ║   1  ║
╚══════╩═══════════╩═════════╩═════╩══════╝
```

## Addendum

You should alter your schema. Add primary key to `tbl_reaction_item` and use `reid` as foreign key.

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.reaction
FROM tbl_reaction t1
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT reid, CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN type='income' THEN CONCAT(IF(num=1, '', num),substance) END SEPARATOR ' + '), ' => ',
             GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN type='outcome' THEN CONCAT(IF(num=1, '', num),substance) END SEPARATOR ' + '))
             AS reaction
  FROM tbl_reaction_item
  GROUP BY reid
) t2
  ON t1.id = t2.reid
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo2`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/977a1/2/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═════╦════════════╦═════════════╦══════════╦══════════════════╗
║ id  ║ condition  ║ phenomenon  ║  infor   ║     reaction     ║
╠═════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╬══════════════════╣
║  1  ║ abcd123    ║ abcd123     ║ abcd123  ║ 2H2 + O2 => 2H2O ║
║  2  ║ wer        ║ wer         ║ wer      ║ (null)           ║
╚═════╩════════════╩═════════════╩══════════╩══════════════════╝
```

Comment: you are so great. Master lab2015

Comment: Can you give me another favour, please lab2025? If i need to display the reaction with its condition, phenomon and information which are in the first table tbl_reaction like this result structure:
| reaction | condition | phenomon | information

Comment: @deango How  are the both tables connected? Your second table does not have foreign key defined

Comment: Yes, my mistake. Foreign key is reid in tbl_reaction_item, and primary key is id in tbl_reaction

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so much! You are so supported, lab2025. I hope you can see my face now. I am so happy.

Answer (score 0):

I like lad's SQL solution, but you could also do it with PHP.  Note that I haven't tested it, and think I have an error with the adding of strings, but you get the idea.

```
$income=[];
$outcome=[];
$stmt=$conn->prepare('SELECT substance,type,num FROM tbl_reaction_item WHERE reid=?');
$stmt->execute(array(1));
while($row=$stmt->fetch()){
    if($row->type=='income') {$income[]=$row->num+$row->substance;}
    else {$outcome[]=$row->num+$row->substance;}
}
echo(implode(' + ',$income).' => '.implode(' + ',$outcome));
```